# How to break out of an IBAction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I have a ViewController which contains a few textfields. If these textfields are blank and the user wants to tap the "save" button, I don't want the user to be able to save. I want them to be exited out of the IBAction and nothing to be saved. How would I go about doing that exactly?

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

if ([personYouOweMoney.text isEqualToString: @" "] && [amtYouOwe.text isEqualToString:@" "])
{
    //GET OUTTA THIS DANG IBACTION
}
```

Comment: `personYouOweMoney.text.length == 0` is better than @" ",`@" "` is not  an empty string.

Comment: IBActions are just method within a object.  Nothing special about it really. maybe a little reading about simple programming fundimentals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want them to be exited out of the IBAction and nothing to be saved.

You can do it by checking a condition and returning, like this:

```
if (/*all fields are empty*/) {
    return;
}
```

However, this would be a wrong thing to do from the perspective of the user interface design. Your end users would believe that something has happened, since they were allowed to tap the button. A better approach would be disabling the `[Save]` button when all entry fields are empty, and re-enabling it only when there is something to save. This would leave no ambiguity in end users' minds as to why the system did not save things, because they would know that the saving is impossible until they type something (if this is not obvious from the context, consider adding a message to this effect right next to your disabled button).

Comment: That sounds a lot better actually. How could I code my button so it's not enabled until all the fields are entered?

Comment: @doc92606 that'd be an entirely different question altogether

Comment: @doc92606 You do it in the event handler(s) of your fields (they can all share a single handler, unless they have specific needs). The handler would check if all fields are empty or not. If all are empty, it would set `saveButton.enabled = NO`; otherwise, it would set `saveButton.enabled = YES`.

Comment: Ah I was able to figure out right after I asked that silly question xD so sorry, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Wait when I do  if (amtYouOwe.text.length == 0 && personYouOweMoney.text.length == 0 && self.cellNum.text.length == 0)
    {
        saveButton.enabled = NO;
    }
in my ViewDidLoad the button is NEVER enabled even if all the textfields are filled out. But if i put the same code in the save button IBAction then button is always enabled even if the uitextfields are empty. Where would I put this code then?

Comment: @doc92606 You missed the "otherwise" part of my comment above: your `if` needs an `else`.

Answer (score 1):

IBAction is the same thing as void (except that Xcode knows it should be hooked up to an action in Interface Builder).

To exit out of the method, you just use return, same as you'd do to exit out of any other void method:

```
return;
```